# town tournament question

Tags: geometry

a) Given a $10$-gon (not necessary convex). Draw circles with its sides as diameters. Is it possible that all these circles pass through a point which is not a vertex of this $10$-gon?

b) Solve the same problem for an $11$-gon.

Comment: The problem as stated by you is trivial. Of course these circles pass through points not even _on_ the polygon. And if you take the regular one, they only pass through the vetices of the polygon. Or are you asking for a common point of the circles?

Comment: Also consider choosing a question title that describes the problem instead of making us think that we are doing your tournament tasks.

Comment: Would you please stop posting questions with the stupid title, "town tornoment question"? The title is supposed to give some idea of what the question is about, and to help people find the question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

From Thales' theorem, we know that each of the sides of the decagon together with the point $P$ (which is the potentially existing point which is common to all the circles that have the sides of the decagon as diameters) form a triangle with a right angle at $P$. Therefore, each of the vertices of the decagon must lie on one of two lines which intersect at $P$ with a right angle, and the order of the vertices must be such that the two lines are visited in alternating order. This is very well possible for a decagon (even without intersection):
$$(1,0)\rightarrow
(0,-2)\rightarrow
(3,0)\rightarrow
(0,-4)\rightarrow
(5,0) \\
\rightarrow
(0,5)\rightarrow
(-4,0)\rightarrow
(0,3)\rightarrow
(-2,0)\rightarrow
(0,1)\rightarrow
(1,0)
$$
As the two orthogonal lines are visited in alternating order when we travel from one vertex to the next one, the number of vertices must be even. Therefore there cannot be a point $P$ with the requested properties for a hendecagon.